# Не запускается проект AndroidStudio Gradle build finished with 41 error(s) (Красным код, где используются ресурсы: R)

Tags: android, android-studio, android-sdk

Срочно! нерешаемая проблема.... Обновила Android Studio и тут пошло поехало...

При запуске нового проекта выдает ошибку: 
***Gradle build finished with 41 error(s)***


Пыталась лечить:

- 1) Чистила libraries и синхронизировала
- 2) Переустанавливала студию и SDK
- 3) Удаляла папку build и строила заново (а вдруг)
- 4) Ставила меньшую версию API в приложении

Но ничего не помогло... как можно его вылечить? Очень прошу помощи... Надежда только на Вас!
Скриншот ошибки снизу

[image: Ошибка Android Studio Gradle build]

[image: build.gradle]

**APP:**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.ebalabanova.ttt"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'
}
```

**Project:**

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to 
// all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {

    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1'


        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Есть еще варианты? Мне кажется уже проще сжечь ее)

Comment: Попробуйте `Invalidate cache and restart` в студии сделать. Если не поможет - попробуйте ещё и папку `gradle` в проекте удалить. Также, думаю, тестовые зависимости вам не нужны и их тоже можно удалить, чтобы они не мешались: `testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'` и `testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"`

Comment: @ ЮрийСПб Invalidate cache and restart - делала. Не помог рестарт(  Удалила все, что Вы писали папку gradle и записи. увы та же самая ошибка(

Comment: Хм... А вы точно ничего не меняли? Может у вас в строковых ресурсах невалидные строки? Они могут так сломать проект. Попробуйте ещё полезное что-то в `gradle console` найти - может быть в логах там что-то полезное есть.

Comment: Я бы с удовольствием все настройки сбросила, но переустановка и удаление всех файлов AndroidStudio ни к чему не приводит. Пару раз все заново устанавливала и ничего, каждый раз одна и та же ошибка. Не хочет лечиться(

Comment: Т.е. в `strings.xml` ничего нет? нет `%` или других спец символов?

Comment: В **Gradle Console**: * What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.
> Failed to execute aapt. В **strings.xml**: <resources>
    <string name="app_name">test1</string>
</resources>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Решила свою проблему. Может кому понадобиться. Но это было не просто, в ход пошло все!
1) Удалила Android Studio через uninstall в папке. Открыла все "скрытые папки" и нашла в своем аккаунте (С-пользователи-"имя пользователя") файлы .android, .gradle. Видимо отсюда он настройки брал, не знаю, все было беспощадно удалено!

2) Загрузила старую версию Android Studio 2.3.3 и установила на диск D
Все по алгоритму: http://startandroid.ru/ru/uroki/vse-...azrabotki.html

3) Получила ошибку (26,13) - прописала в build.gradle(Module:app) :

```js
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
```

4) Получила ошибку (27,13) - установила все API c 4 android

5) После опять красным выделилась надпись

```js
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
```

Решение: Cлева переключиться на Project, открыть каталог .idea, затем каталог libraries и из него удалить все содержимое. Затем нажать кнопку Sync Project. А затем (если все еще красное, но скорее всего уже будет все ок ) Build -> Clean Project.

и Работает! юху! Больше никаких обновлений! Это была жесть)

Answer (score 0):

Решением проблемы просто, вам необходимо проверить Activity , у одного или более сбилась ссылка на Java файл.

Comment: Переустановила сейчас JDK, прописала в переменных JAVA_Home и в Path новый путь, в "Andr.Stud." File->Project Structure ->JDK прописан путь к встроенному "C-Program Felis-Android-AndroidStudio-jre" если прописывать свой, то выдает ошибку: Error: Could not determine java version from '9.0.4'....